# Sort tenors in finance notation

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, numpy, finance

I have an array of tenors

```
Tenors = np.array(['10Y', '15Y', '1M', '1Y', '20Y', '2Y', '30Y', '3M', '5Y', '6M', '9M'])
```

where `M` stands for month and `Y` stands for years. The correctly sorted order (ascending) would then be

```
['1M', '3M', '6M', '9M', '1Y', '2Y', '5Y', '10Y', '15Y', '20Y', '30Y']
```

How do I achieve that using python with scipy/numpy? As the `tenors` originate from a `pandas` dataframe a solution based on `pandas` would be fine as well.

Comment: Make tenors [categorical data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html).

Comment: Could you have a tenor value of "18M"?

Comment: @Jim In principle yes, but afaik it is not used in the market.

Comment: Btw, is this some kind of trolling?

Comment: No, not trolling. Whether "18M" can exist makes a big difference in how the solution is structured. If we know that any tenor longer than 11 months will be expressed in years, then we can automatically assume that all tenors expressed in years will sort after any tenor that is expressed in months. But if "18M" is allowed, then you need code that will give you, for example, `["1Y", "18M", "2Y"]`. That's a more complicated problem. And, are you *sure* that "18M" isn't used? I seem to remember notes that had terms in partial years (18 months was a pretty popular term when I was working in banks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1** Here's a NumPy based approach using [`np.core.defchararray.replace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.replace.html#numpy.core.defchararray.replace) -

```
repl = np.core.defchararray.replace
out = Tenors[repl(repl(Tenors,'M','00'),'Y','0000').astype(int).argsort()]
```

---

**Approach #2** If you are working with strings like `'18M'`, we need to do a bit more of work, like so -

```
def generic_case_vectorized(Tenors):
    # Get shorter names for functions
    repl = np.core.defchararray.replace
    isalph = np.core.defchararray.isalpha

    # Get scaling values
    TS1 = Tenors.view('S1')
    scale = repl(repl(TS1[isalph(TS1)],'Y','12'),'M','1').astype(int)

    # Get the numeric values
    vals = repl(repl(Tenors,'M',''),'Y','').astype(int)

    # Finally scale numeric values and use sorted indices for sorting input arr
    return Tenors[(scale*vals).argsort()]
```

**Approach #3** Here's another approach, though a loopy one to again handle generic cases -

```
def generic_case_loopy(Tenors):
    arr = np.array([[i[:-1],i[-1]] for i in Tenors])
    return Tenors[(arr[:,0].astype(int)*((arr[:,1]=='Y')*11+1)).argsort()]
```

Sample run -

```
In [84]: Tenors
Out[84]: 
array(['10Y', '15Y', '1M', '1Y', '20Y', '2Y', '30Y', '3M', '25M', '5Y',
       '6M', '18M'], 
      dtype='|S3')

In [85]: generic_case_vectorized(Tenors)
Out[85]: 
array(['1M', '3M', '6M', '1Y', '18M', '2Y', '25M', '5Y', '10Y', '15Y',
       '20Y', '30Y'], 
      dtype='|S3')

In [86]: generic_case_loopy(Tenors)
Out[86]: 
array(['1M', '3M', '6M', '1Y', '18M', '2Y', '25M', '5Y', '10Y', '15Y',
       '20Y', '30Y'], 
      dtype='|S3')
```

Comment: What happens if a tenor is, for example, "18M"?

Comment: @JimMischel Added approaches to handle such cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for parsing numbers and values, then convert to `int` and `categories` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and last [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':Tenors})
df[['b','c']] = df.a.str.extract("(\d+)([MY])", expand=True)
df.b = df.b.astype(int)
df.c = df.c.astype('category', ordered=True, categories=['M','Y'])
df = df.sort_values(['c','b'])
print (df)
      a   b  c
2    1M   1  M
7    3M   3  M
9    6M   6  M
10   9M   9  M
3    1Y   1  Y
5    2Y   2  Y
8    5Y   5  Y
0   10Y  10  Y
1   15Y  15  Y
4   20Y  20  Y
6   30Y  30  Y

print (df.a.tolist())
['1M', '3M', '6M', '9M', '1Y', '2Y', '5Y', '10Y', '15Y', '20Y', '30Y']
```

Comment: What happens if a tenor is, for example, "18M"?

Comment: Then it sorts bad this values like `18M`, but OP has no such value.

Answer (score 1):

```
print sorted(Tenors, key=lambda Tenors: (Tenors[-1], int(Tenors[:-1])))
```

Sorts by the last character and then by the integer value up to the last character

Comment: What happens if a tenor is, for example, "18M"?

Comment: Didn't think of that: Possible to chnage it so that it sorts on total months. Therefore if there is a Y, mutilply the value by 12 `if x[:-1]=='Y' then x[:-1]*12 else x[:-1]`

Answer (score 0):

I opted for the long solution since I needed `convert_tenors` anyway. This also solves [Jim's objection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742758/sort-tenors-in-finance-notation/39752239#comment66797667_39742758).

```
import scipy

def convert_tenors(tenors):
    #convert tenors to years
    new_tenors = scipy.zeros_like(tenors,dtype=float)
    for i,o in enumerate(tenors):
        if(o[-1]=='M'):
            new_tenors[i] = int(o[:-1])/12
        else:
            new_tenors[i] = int(o[:-1])
    return new_tenors

def sort_tenors(tenors):
    #sort tenors in ascending order
    idx = scipy.argsort(convert_tenors(tenors))
    return tenors[idx]  

Tenors = scipy.array(['10Y', '15Y', '1M', '1Y', '20Y', '18M', '2Y', '30Y', '3M', '5Y', '6M', '9M'])
print(sort_tenors(Tenors))
```

returns

```
['1M' '3M' '6M' '9M' '1Y' '18M' '2Y' '5Y' '10Y' '15Y' '20Y' '30Y']
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution — convert the tenors their day equivalent, then sort based on that:

```
def tenor_to_days(tenor):
    """
    Convert a tenor string (e.g., '1M', '2Y') to a number of days.
    
    Args:
    tenor (str): The tenor string to convert.
    
    Returns:
    int: The number of days in the tenor.
    
    Raises:
    ValueError: If the tenor string is not in a recognized format (e.g., contains invalid characters).
    """
    unit = tenor[-1].lower()
    value = int(tenor[:-1])
    if unit == 'w':
        days = 7 * value
    elif unit == 'm':
        days = 30 * value
    elif unit == 'y':
        days = 365 * value
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unrecognized tenor unit: {unit}")
    if days < 0:
        raise ValueError("Tenor must be non-negative")
    return days

tenors = ['10Y', '15Y', '1M', '1Y', '20Y', '2Y', '30Y', '3M', '5Y', '6M', '9M', '18M']
sorted(tenors, key=lambda tenor: tenor_to_days(tenor))
# ['1M', '3M', '6M', '9M', '1Y', '18M', '2Y', '5Y', '10Y', '15Y', '20Y', '30Y']
```